# Fill input value only if data present with react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Having this input field that is part of a questionnaire with next/back buttons like this:

[image: input and buttons]

`<input id="answer"/>`

I am storing the value the user writes when clicks on next/back buttons, for example:

```
const [quizIndex, setIndex] = useState(0)
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({})

const back = () => {
    var answersCopy = answers
    answersCopy[quizIndex] = document.getElementById("answer").value
    setAnswers(answersCopy)
    document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
    setIndex(quizIndex + 1)
}

<Button onClick={back}</Button>
```

Now, I want:

1. To show the user, if comes back to an already responded question, their previous response in the input field.
2. Also if the user wants to update the answer, is able to do so.

How can I do it using **exclusively functional react components**?

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you can need to store the variables in either global level state(like redux) or as state variable in higher of all the other components so that you can access that variable even after it is passed or again coming back to it. Here is the example.

```
import react, {useState} from 'react';

const app = () => {
   const [formdata, setFormdata] = useState({});
   return (<>
     <Formslider formdata={formdata} setFormdata={setFormdata} />
  </>);
}

export default app;
```

and now in Formslider you can use the data from formdata to set each time someone opens it and update the formdata when user enter/edit the value.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not applicable directly to my input field. I am waiting for something more tied to my question

Comment: Yes @Arcones this is not directly applicable since I am not aware of your project structure. Could you tell the structure of your project and if you're using redux or any other global state management ? If possible please share you're code via github.

Comment: I am just using react hooks, avoiding explicitly redux